# How to color plot by increasing shade of a color by the values of a categorical column using plot() function R

Tags: r, plot

I have a dataframe that contains 3 columns and I'm trying to plot car crashes vs. losses colored by categorical column year where each year will be assigned a different shade of color. I want the color to be shade of a color from lightest to darkest. For example the minimum year in the dataframe is 1946 and maximum year is 2003 hence 1946 should be the lightest shade of the color assigned and 2003 should be the darkest. I'm able to color the plot by year but I observed same set of colors of assigned to every couple of years. I want the year progress to be visually distinguishable. Below is the minimum reproducible dataframe and my attept so far.

```r
# creating dataframe
year <- data.frame(year = seq(1946,2003,1))
crashes <- data.frame(crashes = c(386,317,294,287,266,245,268,296,226,265,243,239,183,212,195,224,170,169,140, 147,111,119,100,115,128,111,80,77,68,69,84,72,90,82,59,67,45,59,50,64,55,63,56,56,57,68,34,32,26,21,20,30,35,28  ,22,27,34,NA))
losses <- data.frame(losses = c(432,423,341,291,282,288,387,323,229,305,244,333,200,215,211,245,197,177,153,152, 115,189,124,129,133,120,91,90,69,78,88,77,95,98,62,70,45,62,70,68,65,73,90,65,61,74,39,33,31,22,21,39,35,58,25,36 ,40,NA))
df <- cbind(year,crashes,losses)
# plotting
plot(df$crashes, df$losses, main = "Sum of Car Crashes and the Total sum of Losses per Year",xlab = "Car Crashes", ylab = "Losses", col = df$year)
legend(x = 401,y = 510, legend = df$year,cex=.3, fill = df$year, xpd=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a colour palette by specifying how many colours you need (length(df$year)) and simply use it as argument of your plot statement.

```
mypalette <- rainbow(length(df$year))
plot(df$crashes, df$losses, main = "Sum of Car Crashes and the Total sum of Losses per Year",xlab = "Car Crashes", ylab = "Losses", col = mypalette)
```

Example for multiple colours with the viridis palette :

```
install.packages("viridis")  # Install
library("viridis")           # Load
palette <- viridis(length(df$year))
plot(df$crashes, df$losses, main = "Sum of Car Crashes and the Total sum of Losses per Year",xlab = "Car Crashes", ylab = "Losses", col = palette)
```

More palette colours : https://www.datanovia.com/en/blog/top-r-color-palettes-to-know-for-great-data-visualization/